# Working with objects and creating methods in JavaScript that return values

Tags: javascript, object, methods

This has been driving me crazy because I can't find anything on Google. Maybe it's because I don't know the right terminology to search right. But this is what I'm trying to do.

I want to create a function that acts like an object. I'm think it's called a method, though I could be wrong.

Check this out, this is some pseudocode of what I would like it to do.

```
function myMethod(){
var p = this.getAttribute('x');
var p = p+1;
return p;
}

function otherFunction(){
var q = document.getElementByID('Element').myMethod();
alert(q);
}
```

So, I can't get this to work. It keeps saying `myMethod()` is `undefined` and not a function.

Comment: are you trying to call myMethod on the 'Element' that is found using the document.getElementById()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `myMethod` to be available on elements, you'd have to append it to elements' *prototype*.

```
Element.prototype.myMethod = myMethod;
```

The concept of `prototype` is big, but it comes down to the fact that instances of functions have a function available in the way that you describe as 'like an object'.

In this case, any element on the page is an instance of the `Element` function. Therefore, any element will have `.myMethod` available, which you can call. (`Element` is a function although you don't really deal with that - the instances are available because you put them there in HTML, so you bypass using `Element`.)

Second, if you have `var p`, then another `var p` does not make much sense. Just use `p = p + 1`, or `p++` (shortcut for adding one).

Comment: The Element and HTMLElement interfaces (and the rest & their prototypes) aren't exposed in IE7 and below, might be something to watch out for.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myMethod(element){
    var p = element.getAttribute('x');
    var p = p+1;
    return p;
}

function otherFunction(){
    var q = myMethod(document.getElementByID('Element'));
    alert(q);
}
```

Obviously, it would be better to not declare these in the global scope, but basically is that javascript is looking for a `myMethod()` that is a member of the DOM Element you are selecting, but you have actually declared the function standing alone.

Another option would be to add the method via prototype inheritance.